# very simple code throws me : generator object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Here is my current code.

```
def get_unique_value(state):
    unique_value = 0
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            unique_value += int((10**(i*3+j))*(state[i][j]))
```

which throws me a `TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable`

here, state is a 3x3 numpy array, each having a value of 0, 1, or 2

Comment: Don't you return `unique_value`?

Comment: Please, share the whole traceback

Comment: We need a [mcve]. How do you call `get_unique_value`, and how do you construct the value passed as an argument?

Comment: Hi, please provide more details so others can reproduce it. Particularly, please show how you are calling this function and what you are passing as the `state` argument.

Comment: `state` or `state[i]` is a generator.

Comment: I added return unique_value, didn't fix, but youre right

Comment: How do you create `state` variable. Please update your code with `state = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works:

```
def get_unique_value(state):
    unique_value = 0
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            unique_value += int((10**(i*3+j))*(state[i][j]))
    return unique_value

state = np.random.randint(0, 4, (3,3))
print(get_unique_value(state))

# Output:
13233303
```

So I think `state` is not a numpy array, check:

```
>>> type(state)
numpy.ndarray
```

Reproducible error:

```
>>> state = (i for i in range(1))  # different from [i for i in range(1)]

>>> type(state)
generator

>>> get_unique_value(state)
...
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: thank you. I love you. State was not np array for some reason